# Kotlin: Backend Internal error: Error during File Facade generation

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

This error initially occurred when I was trying to set up a kotlin project with the processing library(using a preset that had worked in the past). However, i have done some testing and this error occurs every time i make a kotlin project.

some extra info: SDK: OpenJDK 14.0.2 but this happens with every one

this is the simplest code that causes the issue:

```
fun main(){
}
```

this is the output:

```
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during file facade code generation
File being compiled: file://C:/Users/mcleg/Documents/processingtest/src/Main.kt
The root cause java.io.FileNotFoundException was thrown at: java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:634)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1479)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\mcleg\Documents\processingtest\out\production\processingtest\MainKt.class (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:291)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:234)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1060)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1054)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1039)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.output.OutputUtilsKt.writeAll(outputUtils.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.output.OutputUtilsKt.writeAll(outputUtils.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.writeOutput(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.access$writeOutput(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$createOutputFilesFlushingCallbackIfPossible$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$createOutputFilesFlushingCallbackIfPossible$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationStateKt$GenerationStateEventCallback$1.invoke(GenerationState.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationStateKt$GenerationStateEventCallback$1.invoke(GenerationState.kt:353)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState.afterIndependentPart(GenerationState.kt:310)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:71)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Does it occur also with Gradle or Maven projects created from New project wizard in IDEA? There may be something wrong with file permissions on your system.

Comment: I was having the same problem in a Spring MVC maven project created with IntelliJ 2020.3. The problem was caused by the permissions of the target directory.